# Meteor: Proper way to add 'confirm delete' modal

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a confirm delete popup with Bootstrap 3. Is there any good comprehensive examples how to build one. I am very new to Meteor.

Comment: I've created a [package for showing modals in bootstrap 3](https://atmospherejs.com/peppelg/bootstrap-3-modal). Feel free to use it, or take a look at [the source code](https://github.com/PeppeL-G/bootstrap-3-modal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use whatever example from Codrops, etc, just remember put the JSCode inside a

```
Template.nameTemplate.rendered = function() {}
```

So thats telling meteor to load that jscode, when the template has beed rendered and it can load any modal, etc...

So just follow whatever example you want, and just put whatever jQuery plugin etc, inside Rendered function

Also in some case the rendered its not enough, you need to use too,you can see timer docs [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/timers), anyways if you are having bad time, feel free to upload, some meteorPad, free nitrous box o repo on github and i can help you (i have a bad time with those modals on meteor to, they are a little trickys =p)

**update answer**

try to add `meteor add iron:router`, and on the client /app.js

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('leaderboard');
});
```

And keep the same rendered like this.

```
    Template.deleteBtn.rendered = function(){

  $('.open-modal').on('click', function(e){
    $('#confirm').modal()
        .on('click', '#delete', function (e) {
            // Remove selected player
            Players.remove(Session.get("selectedPlayer"));

        });
  });
  }
```

**UPDATE**

So using the `peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal`Package, you can easy do the follow

First Create a template with the modal content

```
<template name="modal">
<!-- Modal Stuff -->
</template>
```

and easy call it on a Event handler.

```
Template.example.events({
 'click #exampleButton':function(){
   Modal.show('modal')
  }
})
```

Now back to this example check [this meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/D9bw8E5tet75daaMY/Leaderboard) from line 1-23 on `app.'s` and 41-62 on `main.html`

Comment: Thanks very much!

Here is a meteorPad example which I can't get working: http://meteorpad.com/pad/kYnewsoWQZ6nhKzsf/Copy%20of%20Leaderboard

I tried to add this example to MeteorPad:
http://jsfiddle.net/L3ddq/197/

Comment: Not problem , let me see

Comment: [this](http://intense-white-harbor-69-177465.sae1.nitrousbox.com/) is ok for you?

Comment: check the update answer, but like i say the idea its to initialize the modal inside the `rendered` function, tell me if work with the iron router

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68427/discussion-between-etjana-and-mika-vaisanen).

Comment: @Mika Väisänen if my first answer help you, could you please Accept or upvote it? thanks

Comment: I still haven't got it working. Please see the chat.

Comment: @MikaVäisänen im on the chat now